# Use SQL to count cases in a certain state at a certain time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I need to develop a query that will count the total number of 'open' cases per month.
I have a 'cases' table with an id and a name, and a 'state_changes' table with a datetime column, a caseid column and a state.

How can I calculate the number of cases in each month that have a record with state 'open' in the past, but without a corresponding record with state closed?

I'm using SQL server 2000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you close (T-SQL):

```
SELECT
  MONTH(s.casedate) m,
  YEAR(s.casedate)  y,
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.caseid)   count_cases
FROM
  cases c
  INNER JOIN state_changes s ON s.caseid = c.caseid
WHERE
  s.state = 'open'           /* "with state 'open'" */
  AND s.casedate < GETDATE() /* "in the past" */
  AND NOT EXISTS (           /* "without corresp. record with state 'closed'" */
    SELECT 1 FROM state_changes i WHERE i.caseid = s.caseid AND i.state = 'closed'
  )
GROUP BY
  MONTH(s.casedate),
  YEAR(s.casedate)
```

EDIT: To make a statistic over all twelve months (independent of actual cases existing in these months) you need a small helper table (let's call it `month`), that contains nothing but one column (let's call that `month` as well) with numbers from 1 to 12. Then you join against it:

```
SELECT
  m.month,
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.caseid) count_cases
FROM
  cases c
  INNER JOIN state_changes s ON s.caseid = c.caseid
  LEFT  JOIN month         m ON m.month  = MONTH(s.casedate)
WHERE
  s.state = 'open'
  AND YEAR(c.createddate) = YEAR(GETDATE())  /* whatever */
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM state_changes i WHERE i.caseid = s.caseid AND i.state = 'closed'
  )
GROUP BY
  m.month
ORDER BY
  m.month
```

Comment: It depends. Future cases may not be impossible, and since the OP explicitly mentioned it…

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with this. Problem now is I need to know the count in a each month, which is not the same as the month of the casedate. I'll try and update when I have something

Comment: Then you need a small helper table that goes from 1 to 12 so you have something to join to and to group on.

Answer (score 1):

Create a query of the state changes tables for open events and one for close events.

Create a query that does an outer join of the open to the closed on the case ID returning the case ID from both queries

Query the latter query result for rows where the ID from the "close" event query is null

Count the number of rows in the latter query result.

Something very roughly like (off the top of my head, without correction):

```
SELECT COUNT (T1.CaseID) FROM (SELECT T1.CaseID AS T1_CaseID, T2.CaseID AS T2_CaseID 
FROM ((SELECT CaseID FROM state_changes WHERE state = 'open' AND timestamp BETWEEN 1-Jan-09 AND 30-Jan-09) AS T1 OUTER JOIN (SELECT CaseID FROM state_changes WHERE state = 'closed' AND timestamp BETWEEN 1-Jan-09 AND 30-Jan-09) AS T2 ON T1.CaseID = T2.CaseID)) WHERE T2_CaseID = NULL
```

Comment: Nice allthough now I have to figure out how to group by month